# Anonymous pulls: is Docker Hub rate limit counted separately for two repositories?

Tags: docker, authentication, rate-limiting, dockerhub, quota

.. or do all *anonymous* pulls made from the same IP address (e.g. corporate NAT) get aggregated and collectively count towards that single limit, regardless of the fact that the two Hub repo names are distinct? By that I mean Docker Hub repositories (not client usernames), e.g. `bitnami` in `bitnami/mariadb` vs. `mirekphd` in `mirekphd/ml-mariadb`.

The [docs](https://docs.docker.com/docker-hub/download-rate-limit/) are ambiguous on this issue:

"Docker Hub limits the number of Docker image downloads (“pulls”) based on the account type of the user pulling the image. Pull rates limits are based on individual IP address. For anonymous users, the rate limit is set to 100 pulls per 6 hours per IP address." [..] "Unauthenticated (anonymous) users will have the limits enforced via IP."

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question... _anonymous_ implies that there are no usernames involved.

Comment: sorry for the confusion, I meant Hub repos (usernames/logins, e.g. bitnami/mariadb vs. library/mariadb) - will add this example

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Anonymous pulls are limited to 100 pulls per 6 hours per IP address. These are pulls and API requests that are not authenticated with username and password.

For authenticated users, it is 200 pulls per 6 hour period and is separate from IP address rate limits, and is separate for every user. However, **you must [authenticate your pulls](https://docs.docker.com/docker-hub/download-rate-limit/#how-do-i-authenticate-pull-requests)**.

The limits are irrespective of the specific repo you are pulling. Rate limits are enforced on the client, not the repository. Whether you are pulling an official image (eg `docker pull python`), a namespaced image (eg `bitnami/foobar`), or a private repo, they are all counted the same towards your API limits when you pull.

Comment: Perfect and straight to the point. Thank you, this saved us a lot of searching!